# 2checkout sandbox mode is not working

Tags: sandbox, error-code, 2checkout

After many tries, I could not get an Authorized response from 2checkout, for each try with valid data I got the next response:

```
{
  "validationErrors": null,
  "response": null,
  "exception": {
    "errorMsg": "Payment Authorization Failed: Please verify your information and try again, or try another payment method.",
    "httpStatus": "400",
    "exception": false,
    "errorCode": "607"
  }
}
```

what does mean 607 error code?

Comment: After a while researching about this, 2CO confirmed that is a problem on its side, the we have to wait to have this fixed.
I just tested in sandbox mode.

Answer (score 0):

607 Error code is a general code for rejected credit card authorization. For example, a credit card could be declined by its bank due to insufficient funds, expiration or some similar problems.

2Checkout has a test account for checking this case:
CC with number 4333************

https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/sandbox/test-data